# What is the error in this xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I want the path to be filled by prograssbar but here is happening something else

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ProgressBar" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="slider"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Orientation="Horizontal"
                   Value="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" Foreground="#FFD81818" Background="{x:Null}">
            <ProgressBar.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                       <Path Name="PART_Track" Height="26" Canvas.Left="37" Opacity="0.702" Canvas.Top="30" 
                                Stroke="Black" 
                                StrokeThickness="5" 
                                    Data="F1M307.5,21.75C303.765,21.75 300.51,19.701 298.793,16.667 298.793,16.667 242.207,16.667 242.207,16.667 240.49,19.701 237.235,21.75 233.5,21.75 229.765,21.75 226.51,19.701 224.793,16.667 224.793,16.667 168.207,16.667 168.207,16.667 166.49,19.701 163.235,21.75 159.5,21.75 155.765,21.75 152.51,19.701 150.793,16.667 150.793,16.667 94.207,16.667 94.207,16.667 92.49,19.701 89.235,21.75 85.5,21.75 81.765,21.75 78.51,19.701 76.793,16.667 76.793,16.667 20.207,16.667 20.207,16.667 18.49,19.701 15.235,21.75 11.5,21.75 5.977,21.75 1.5,17.273 1.5,11.75 1.5,6.227 5.977,1.75 11.5,1.75 15.167,1.75 18.37,3.724 20.111,6.667 20.111,6.667 76.889,6.667 76.889,6.667 78.63,3.724 81.833,1.75 85.5,1.75 89.167,1.75 92.37,3.724 94.111,6.667 94.111,6.667 150.889,6.667 150.889,6.667 152.63,3.724 155.834,1.75 159.5,1.75 163.167,1.75 166.37,3.724 168.111,6.667 168.111,6.667 224.889,6.667 224.889,6.667 226.63,3.724 229.834,1.75 233.5,1.75 237.167,1.75 240.37,3.724 242.111,6.667 242.111,6.667 298.889,6.667 298.889,6.667 300.63,3.724 303.833,1.75 307.5,1.75 313.023,1.75 317.5,6.227 317.5,11.75 317.5,17.273 313.023,21.75 307.5,21.75z"> 
                        </Path>
                        <Path Name="PART_Indicator" Height="26" Canvas.Left="37" Opacity="0.702" Canvas.Top="30" 
                                Stroke="Black" 
                                StrokeThickness="5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    Data="F1M307.5,21.75C303.765,21.75 300.51,19.701 298.793,16.667 298.793,16.667 242.207,16.667 242.207,16.667 240.49,19.701 237.235,21.75 233.5,21.75 229.765,21.75 226.51,19.701 224.793,16.667 224.793,16.667 168.207,16.667 168.207,16.667 166.49,19.701 163.235,21.75 159.5,21.75 155.765,21.75 152.51,19.701 150.793,16.667 150.793,16.667 94.207,16.667 94.207,16.667 92.49,19.701 89.235,21.75 85.5,21.75 81.765,21.75 78.51,19.701 76.793,16.667 76.793,16.667 20.207,16.667 20.207,16.667 18.49,19.701 15.235,21.75 11.5,21.75 5.977,21.75 1.5,17.273 1.5,11.75 1.5,6.227 5.977,1.75 11.5,1.75 15.167,1.75 18.37,3.724 20.111,6.667 20.111,6.667 76.889,6.667 76.889,6.667 78.63,3.724 81.833,1.75 85.5,1.75 89.167,1.75 92.37,3.724 94.111,6.667 94.111,6.667 150.889,6.667 150.889,6.667 152.63,3.724 155.834,1.75 159.5,1.75 163.167,1.75 166.37,3.724 168.111,6.667 168.111,6.667 224.889,6.667 224.889,6.667 226.63,3.724 229.834,1.75 233.5,1.75 237.167,1.75 240.37,3.724 242.111,6.667 242.111,6.667 298.889,6.667 298.889,6.667 300.63,3.724 303.833,1.75 307.5,1.75 313.023,1.75 317.5,6.227 317.5,11.75 317.5,17.273 313.023,21.75 307.5,21.75z">
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ProgressBar.Template>
        </ProgressBar>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

The picture that are produced is like-

[image]

But I want simple this-

[image]

According to the progress value.

Comment: It seems that the `PART_Indicator` has an implicit offset. You could adjust the starting point with a translation and bind the amount to the progress (possibly with some kind of factor).

Comment: Could you tell actually what to change in the above code!

Comment: I'm a afraid I cannot. If the `Canvas.Left` is really used (which you can simply check) you could bin this value to the slider value and use a special (custom) value converter to do the math.

Comment: I am new to .Net, so I hardly understand what your are telling, it would be very helpful to me if you please tell me completely what to change/add in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `Grid` to `Canvas` in the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Canvas Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Path Name="PART_Track" Height="26" Canvas.Left="37" Opacity="0.702" Canvas.Top="30" 
                Stroke="Black" 
                StrokeThickness="5" 
                    Data="...">
        </Path>
        <Path Name="PART_Indicator" Height="26" Canvas.Left="37" Opacity="0.702" Canvas.Top="30" 
                Stroke="Black" 
                StrokeThickness="5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Data="...">
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I did not work, just placed the progressbar above the one. See http://postimg.org/image/fcmmjlf05/

Comment: @RupamBhaduri  Worked for me, see result image; It seems like you dropped the `Canvas.Top/Left` attributes from `PART_Indicator`. That's giving you the offset. The must be the same for `PART_Track` and `PART_Indicator`